# Read the file name using tag <input type = "file" > while uploading and rename it mvc + angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to read the file name while uploading and rename it,save it to a path. For uploading the file I am using an upload image placed in a table. I am using -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("file", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

to read the file name and the row values. But the issue is it reads the value of only first row whereever I click. Here is my code -

**HTML** -

```html
<div>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("file", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "{{data in list}}">
          <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Id}}</td>
          <td>
            <label for="file">
              <i class="fa fa-upload" id="hello" aria-hidden="true" >
              </i>
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
            <input type="text" name="Id" id="Id" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    }

</div>
```

**Controller -**

```html
public ActionResult file(HttpPostedFileBase file, string Name, string Id)
    {

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string newName = Name;
            string fileId = Id;
         }   
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
        return View("UploadPage");
    }
```

Atpresent this is working but when I click on any upload image button, it only takes the first row Name and Id. I am not able to fix it. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: _"But the issue is it reads the value of only first row whereever I click"_ The form is submitted `change` event.

Comment: @guest271314  Sorry I didn't understand. Can you explain me why it's happening and how I can fix it.  Thanks

Comment: You changed `html` from original Question. WHat issue are you having getting name of `File` object?

Comment: @guest271314  I am able to get the file name... I want to rename the file for the particular row the file is uploaded. So with the file name, I am passing the selected row value from the table. The upload icon is present in all the rows . So when I click on any row, it takes the file name but takes only the first row data even if the 3rd row is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting first row because when `this.form.submit();` event triggers it will submit the form with all the rows in it and in action its just `HttpPostedFileBase` not `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` so it will get the data of first row because it will match the parameter. so one solution is you do

```
public ActionResult file(List<HttpPostedFileBase> file, List<string> Name, List<string> Id)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < file.Count; i++)
               {

                   var name = Name[i];
               } 

        }
```

and a better way is to use a `class`

```
public class UploadFiles
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

and your view will be

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("file", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
           <table>
            <tr ng-repeat = "{{data in list}}">
             <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
             <td>{{data.Id}}</td>
             <td>
                <label for="file">
                 <i class="fa fa-upload" id="hello" aria-hidden="true" >
                 </i>
                </label>
                <input type="file" name="files[{{$index}}].File" id="file" />
                <input type="text" name="files[{{$index}}].Name" id="Name" />
                <input type="text" name="files[{{$index}}].Id" id="Id" />
              </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <button type="submit" >Upload All</button>

          }
</div>
```

and in your `action`

```
 public ActionResult AddAuto(List<UploadFiles> files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        // here you can access properties e.g file.File 
                    }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks... I think I didn't explain my question properly. I was not able to send the selected row value from the table. But it helped by adding the List and I passed the index of selected row, so I could get the selected data.